# How to make YOLOv8 output to the input for another program?

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8

I'm new in this field. I'm using YOLOv8 to detect custom objects in realtime. It was implemented successfully. Now, I next want to use the YOLOv8 output for the other inputs. Actually I want to make a program that will talk about the sign language alphabet. The classes are: 'A', 'B', 'C' to 'Z'. I don't know how to do it. Please help me with this.

what I hope is to be able to provide a sample code yolov8 with text to speech output of sign language alphabets in real time to detect it

```
import torch
import cv2
from numpy import ndarray as nd
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('models/best.pt')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

frame_rate = 30
delay = int(1000 / frame_rate)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    results = model(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Detection-Bisindo', nd.squeeze(results[0].plot()))

    if cv2.waitKey(delay) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.